# Using batch to copy files into subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

How do I write a batch file that copies a file in its directory to every one of its subfolders?  Should I use xcopy?

Answer (score 0):

I think that would just be

```
FOR /R %%i in (file.txt) DO copy "file.txt" "%%i"
```

Comment: Yeah mate cheers works like a charm... How does this work btw?

Comment: walks the directory executing the command DO copy "file.txt" "%%i" in each directory. %%i fills in with the current directory plus the name in your set (the (file.txt) ). run for /? in cmd for more info.